# Using Ace Editor as a Polymer Component causes Incorrect Behavior

Tags: clojure, polymer, clojurescript, ace-editor

I am trying to make Ace Editor a web component, however, it seems to be behaving not as it should. Below is a screenshot of what is happening.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBffG.png)

I am getting no error message in the console. Here is my code:

```
<link rel="import" href="components/polymer/polymer.html">
<script src="/ace-builds/src-noconflict/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

<polymer-element name="ace-editor">
    <template>
        <pre id="editor">function foo(items) {
            var x = "All this is syntax highlighted";
            return x;
            }
        </pre>
    </template>
    <script>
        window.addEventListener('polymer-ready', function(e)
        {
            allgress.search_component_polymer.advanced_search.ace_editor();
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Code called on-polymer-ready:

```
(defn ^:export ace-editor []
  (polymer :ace-editor
           {:attached (fn []
                        (this-as this
                                 (let [shadowRoot (.-shadowRoot this)
                                       editor-div (.getElementById shadowRoot "editor")
                                       editor (.edit js/ace editor-div)]
                                   (.setTheme editor "ace/theme/monokai")
                                   (.. editor getSession (setMode "ace/mode/javascript"))
                                   )))}))
```

Definition for polymer function

```
(defn polymer
  [tag-name spec]
  (js/Polymer (name tag-name) (clj->js spec)))
```

The issue is not with the way I am creating the component. The issue is with ace-editor not behaving correctly when used as a component. I have used this same technique to define about 10 other components, all of which would perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because styles added by ace do not have effect on elements inside shadow root see https://github.com/PolymerLabs/ace-element/pull/2 for a related bug on PolymerLabs/ace-element